# Flex-ActionScript :- XML Parsing

Tags: xml, arrays, flash, actionscript-3, apache-flex

Folks,

I have the following `xml` in ActionScript.

```
var xml:XML = <Top>
                <Component>
                   <type>Button</type>
                   <id></id>
                   <width>50</width>
                   <height>20</height>
                   <x>0</x>
                   <y>0</y>
                </Component>
                <Component>
                   <type>Label</type>
                   <id></id>
                   <width>30</width>
                   <height>10</height>
                   <x>0</x>
                   <y>0</y>
                </Component>
             </Top>;
```

Now, I want to read/parse this xml string and then generate Flex controls (i.e Buttons, Label) according to their respective properties.

How to do that ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import flash.xml.XMLDocument;
import mx.rpc.xml.SimpleXMLDecoder;
public static function xmlToObject(x:XML):Object{
    var xmlStr:String = x.toString();
    var xmlDoc:XMLDocument = new XMLDocument(xmlStr);
    xmlDoc.ignoreWhite=true;
    var decoder:SimpleXMLDecoder = new SimpleXMLDecoder(true);
    var resultObj:Object = decoder.decodeXML(xmlDoc);
     return resultObj;
}
```

I use this code to convert xml to Objects. Then it is REALLY simple to use the xml.

For example, your xml would look like:

```
var xml:XML = <Top>
                <Component>
                   <type>Button</type>
                   <id></id>
                   <width>50</width>
                   <height>20</height>
                   <x>0</x>
                   <y>0</y>
                </Component>
                <Component>
                   <type>Label</type>
                   <id></id>
                   <width>30</width>
                   <height>10</height>
                   <x>0</x>
                   <y>0</y>
                </Component>
             </Top>;
```

and

```
var o:Object=xmlToObject(xml);

var top:Object=o.Top;
var componentArrayC:ArrayCollection=top.Component;
for each(var cmp:Object in componentArrayC) {
    //You would have these properties:
    cmp.type;
    cmp.id;
    cmp.width;
    cmp.height;
    cmp.x;
    cmp.y;
}
```

Comment: Can we do it storing in form of name-value pair in some arraycollection/dictionary ? I am not able to do that ...

Comment: Ah well it converts the xml pretty nicely. Then you have o.Top.Component.getItemAt(index) will be an Object (which is a name-value pair basically)

Comment: You are genius man! Flex-guru :) .. your soln worked smoothly. +1 from me and accepting this answer. Thanks once again :)

Answer (score 0):

Use a DataGroup with an itemRendererFunction that returns a ClassFactory based on the properties of your XML.  You don't need to have a separate step to make it into Objects first.  Instead, just do something like this:

```
//yourXML is already populated with your XML
var dataSource:XMLListCollection = new XMLListCollection(yourXML.elements);
//yourDataGroup is defined elsewhere
yourDataGroup.dataProvider = dataSource;
```

For more on using a custom itemRendererFunction, check out
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS77c1dbb1bd80d3836ecbb5ec129ec77b1e1-8000.html#WS94F31173-40D5-4ddd-B7B3-17D02BD57EAF

For information on accessing the properties of the XML through e4x, see
http://dispatchevent.org/roger/as3-e4x-rundown/